# Python 3 Tornado website

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I am trying to create a simple local website using Tornado. When I run this and go to http://localhost:8888, I get the following error: This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. I am still a beginner with python so any help would be much appreciated. My code is shown below.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>" + "Hello world</title></head>" + "<body>Hello World</body>")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/", MainHandler),
                                               ],)
        application.listen(8888)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLOOP.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IOLOOP` should be `IOLoop`:

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
#              ^^^^^
```

---

---

**UPDATE** You need to indent correctly the code. Especially `if __name__ == "__main__":` part, that part should be outside of `class ..` definition:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  # <----
    application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/", MainHandler),
                                           ],)
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I fixed the problem that you pointed out but I still got the same error. Do you know of any other reason why this is not working?

Comment: @ralpher01, Are you running any firewall software? Check its configuration, not to block 8888 port or Python process.

Comment: I am doing this on the raspberry pi model 3 and I have iptables disabled.

Comment: @ralpher01, What do you get if you run `netstat -antp | grep 8888` ?

Comment: I get the following message: (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

Comment: @ralpher01, Ah, root permission is required to use `-p` option: `sudo netstat -antp | grep 8888`

Comment: Nothing happens when I run this in the terminal. I still get the same error. I tried to run this program on my PC and I still got the same error.

Comment: @ralpher01, If you get nothing, it means there's no process that is bound to the port; check you ran the program!

Comment: I did this while the program was running and still nothing happened. I am very sorry as I know it must be frusturating to explain this to a begginner like myself. I am just very lost at this point and eager to fix this problem.

Comment: @ralpher01, Could you ass `print('starting...')` line before the `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` statement to make sure the program is running?

Comment: Oh my god. I am such an idot for not noticing that. Thank you very much. I am very sorry for wasting your time.